# Cannot use courier package and Times New Roman?

Tags: fonts, packages

For whatever reason, when I try to use Times New Roman (i.e., via `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}`) *and* the `courier` package together, LaTeX does not use Courier in `\texttt`... it looks like it uses the regular LaTeX CMU Serif font, but I could be wrong. Is there some conflict between these two, and if so, is there a workaround? For reference, I'm using Overleaf with the XeLaTeX compiler.

**PoC:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\title{Font tests}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. \texttt{This should be in courier but it isn't...}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image: Times New Roman and Courier fonts not working correctly]

Comment: You shouldn't use T1-encoding and the courier package with lualatex and xelatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer TNR requires either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX... so there's no way to use these two together?

Comment: No, use `\setmonofont{Courier New}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `courier` package is a legacy 8-bit font package, so `fontspec` will override it if you load both.

You would want something like,

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
```

or

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
```

This uses GUST’s free clones of Times, Helvetica and Courier.

Comment: You're a champion :-)))) also with the fonts.